# Are "bounties" still useful? Should they be phased out?

Tags: discussion

I used to see a fair number of questions that delivered a "bounty" of points from the questioner's cache if an answer was accepted.

The number of such questions seems to have declined significantly more recently.

Does the "bounty" facility still have a purpose on Stack Exchange sites beyond my experience?

Comment: Can you share the source of your data regarding the significant reduction in use of bounties? It would be helpful for your question and would show us in hard numbers the magnitude of this possible problem.

Comment: @Hovercraft: It is a subjective evaluation. I wondered whether other people had experienced something similar, or had found the system useful?

Comment: Myself I would rather see hard number verification of your subjective evaluation before postulating why the problem exists. It may not even be a problem or issue at all.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I don't think it's a "problem" either way. The facility could remain completely unused without otherwise affecting the functioning of the site. I am simply interested in other people's experience. Perhaps it is less popular than it should be and it needs to be evangelised.

Comment: I don't see any such decline. I follow a RSS feed for Python bounties, and the numbers have remained pretty stable. What evidence do you have?

Comment: @Martijn to play devil's advocate a bit: hasn't traffic in python raised while bounties renained stable maybe? That would cause a drop in the ratio of bounties, even if the question here isn't centered that way (The answer very well may be no btw. Just curious)

Comment: @Patrice: It may have risen, but like the rise in Python questions, its gradual and I haven't paid close attention to exact numbers.

Comment: Bounties are still [running steady at around 2000 per month since 2013](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/771229/bounties-per-month-since-2013#graph). Bounties were still ramping up before that time.

Comment: They are still useful for transferring rep between puppets:)

Comment: @MartinJames: and just as helpful to convince us you knew what you were doing when we find your socks and you used bounties to transfer rep between them. Welcome to the fast lane to a suspension!

Comment: Even if it were true, decreasing the number of open bounties increases the change of each one to be answered, so it is a self-correcting problem.

Comment: @MartijnPieters lol

Comment: You probably know that bounty is not only specific for question, but also possible for notable answer right? Also, I failed to see just because it's declining (according to you) that it needs to be phased out, as long as it's not affecting SE negatively...

Answer (score 2):

As Martijin pointed out in the comments section, there is [plenty of evidence that bounties are still in use](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/771229/bounties-per-month-since-2013#graph).

That being said, while the number of bounties per month is fairly stable, the number of *questions* being asked per month has increased. Therefore, the number of bounties per asked question decreases.

But this is fairly natural. The increase in questions per month is primarily from new users who don't have the rep to add bounties (and people generally don't need to post a bounty for new user questions). So the relative fraction of questions that get bounties tends to decrease.

Overall, the fraction of bountied questions is not that important. What matters is that whether the feature is still doing good. And since it's still in use, it seems clear that it is.